# How to get checkout repository path

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an azure devops pipleline template that checkout multiple repository

```
jobs:
- job: job_name
  steps:
    - checkout: self
    - checkout: repository1
```

I want to run script that will cd into self repository.

Is there a way to get the path that the checkout repository has been downloaded to?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are [pre-defined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), you can see there the variable `Build.SourcesDirectory`:

> The local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded. >For example: c:\agent_work\1\s
>
> By default, new build pipelines update only the changed files.
>
> Important note: If you check out only one Git repository, this path will be >the exact path to the code. If you check out multiple repositories, it will revert to its default value, which is $(Pipeline.Workspace)/s, even if the self (primary) repository is checked out to a custom path different from its multi-checkout default path $(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/ (in this respect, the variable differs from the behavior of the Build.Repository.LocalPath variable).

Comment: If I have multiple checkout the path is "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/RepositoryName".  Is it possible to get "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/RepositoryName" without hardcoding RepsitoryName in the script.

Comment: se it as a parameter in the script and pass the repo name

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with checking out multiple repos and resolved it be using the following path to refer to my "self" repo:

```
$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(Build.Repository.Name)
```